# RODBC error with shiny apps

Tags: r, shiny

I was able to deploy my app with shinyapps but I keep getting error:

```
ERROR: first argument is not an open RODBC channel
```

My app contains 3 files:

```
ui.R
server.R
plots.R
```

plots.R:

```
library(RODBC)
library(ggplot2)

queryfunction <- function(channel) {
    myconn <- odbcConnect(dsn = "SQLServer")   
    query = "my query"
   df <- sqlQuery(channel = myconn, query = query)
   odbcClose(myconn)
   return(df)
    }

plotfunction <- function(channel) {
  a <- ggplot(queryfunction(channel), aes(x = Month, y = Volume)) + 
    geom_bar(stat='identity')
    return(a)
}
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
source('plots.R')
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  #general volume, value, and table plots
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({plotfunction(channel)})
})
```

This works perfectly fine on my own computer, but somehow on the server it doesn't. Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: The ODBC connection on your server may not have the same name.  Can you confirm that there is also a connection named "SQLServer" on your server?

Comment: I updated my myconn to the following: 
"odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver=SQLServer;Server=MBC09DATAMINING;Trusted_Connection = yes;Database=CityWidePaymemts")" and it still does not work

Comment: You may use Windows Authentication or similar in your own computer since you are not adding password/username in your code. I'd create a user for Shiny in SQL Server and use that username and password to connect the database within the app in the server.